# How to call method with parameters using square brackets?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to define a method in a class that, when called, acts like a hash, accepting an argument with `[]` instead of `()`.

```
def content(key)
end
```

I'd like to access it with this kind of syntax: `content[:benefits]` instead of `content(:benefits)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with lambdas

```
content = ->(key) { "content for #{key}" }

content[:benefits] # => "content for benefits"
```

Answer (score 1):

Within `content`'s class

```
def [] key
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to define a method in a class that, when called, acts like a hash

The only way to do that is if the method returns an object that responds to `[]`. See the `params` method in Rails for an example.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a method with no argument, which returns a hash:

```
def content
    {
        :beneficts => 1000
    }
end

p content[:beneficts]
> 1000
```